# How to add active class on child tab when selecting its parent tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

First of all the `"Outer tab 1"` and `"Outer tab 2"` are under `"Main tab 1"` and `"Outer tab 3"` and `"Outer tab 4"` are under `"Main tab 2"`.

Have patience with me, here is what I want. On page load/refresh the `"Main tab 1"` and `"Outer tab 1"` by default are active, and if I click the `"Main tab 2"` the `"Outer tab 3"` became the active tab.

Basically the only missing in my code are the active class on `"Outer..."` tabs when clicking its corresponding `"Main..."` tabs.

To better understand check the code below. Also here is the codepen [https://codepen.io/](https://codepen.io/graydirt/pen/PoXXYZa).

```js
const mainTabs = document.querySelectorAll(".main-tab-btn");
const childTabs = document.querySelectorAll(".child-tab-btn");
const contents = document.querySelectorAll(".content");
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

const childTabsBtn = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab-value]');
const childTabsContent = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab-info]')
    
function SetContent(tabIdx)
{
   // reset all contents
   contents.forEach(content => {
      content.classList.remove("active");
   });
   const content = document.getElementById(tabIdx);
   content.classList.add("active");
}

function ResetButtons(){
   buttons.forEach(btn=> {
     btn.classList.remove("active");
   });
}

// add eventlisteners to all the maintab buttons
mainTabs.forEach(function(tab){
  tab.addEventListener("click", function(e){
     var id = e.target.getAttribute("data-id");
     SetContent(id);
     ResetButtons();
     e.target.classList.add("active");
  });
});

// add eventlisteners to all the childtabs button
childTabs.forEach(function(tab){
  tab.addEventListener("click", function(e){
     var id = e.target.getAttribute("data-id");
     SetContent(id);
     ResetButtons();
     const button = document.querySelector(`.main-tab-btn[data-id="${id}"]`);
      button.classList.add("active");
      e.target.classList.add("active");
  })
})

//outer tab child button and outer content
childTabsBtn.forEach(tab => {
  tab.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const target = document
    .querySelector(tab.dataset.tabValue);
    childTabsContent.forEach(tabInfo => {
      tabInfo.classList.remove('active')
    })
    target.classList.add('active');
  })
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost:wght@100;300;400;700&display=swap');

body {
  font-family: 'Jost', sans-serif;
  background-color: #f0f5ff;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #232c3d;
  text-align:center;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 590px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.buttonWrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

button {
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: none;
}

button.active {
  background-color: orange;
  pointer-events: none
}

.contentWrapper .content {
  display: none;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}

.contentWrapper .content.active {
  display: block;
  background-color: white;
}

[data-tab-info] {
  display: none;
}

.outer-content .active[data-tab-info] {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}
```

```html
<h1>TOGGLE TABS</h1>
  
  <div class="wrapper">
    
    <div class="buttonWrapper">
      <button class="tab-button main-tab-btn active" data-id="maintab1">Main tab 1</button>
      <button class="tab-button main-tab-btn" data-id="maintab2">Main tab 2</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="contentWrapper">
      <div class="content active" id="maintab1">
        Main Tab 1 Content
      </div>
      <div class="content" id="maintab2">
        Main Tab 2 Content
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="outer-tab">
      <button class="child-tab-btn active" data-id="maintab1" data-tab-value="#child-tab-content-1">Outer tab 1</button>
      <button class="child-tab-btn" data-id="maintab1" data-tab-value="#child-tab-content-2">Outer tab 2</button>
      <button class="child-tab-btn" data-id="maintab2" data-tab-value="#child-tab-content-3">Outer tab 3</button>
      <button class="child-tab-btn" data-id="maintab2" data-tab-value="#child-tab-content-4">Outer tab 4</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="outer-content">
      <div class="active" id="child-tab-content-1" data-tab-info>Outer tab 1 content</div>
      <div id="child-tab-content-2" data-tab-info>Outer tab 2 content</div>
      <div id="child-tab-content-3" data-tab-info>Outer tab 3 content</div>
      <div id="child-tab-content-4" data-tab-info>Outer tab 4 content</div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this with your js. It will work

```js
const mainTabs = document.querySelectorAll(".main-tab-btn");
const childTabs = document.querySelectorAll(".child-tab-btn");
const contents = document.querySelectorAll(".content");
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

const childTabsBtn = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab-value]');
const childTabsContent = document.querySelectorAll('[data-tab-info]')
    
function SetContent(tabIdx)
{
   // reset all contents
   contents.forEach(content => {
      content.classList.remove("active");
   });
   const content = document.getElementById(tabIdx);
   content.classList.add("active");
 document.querySelector(`.child-tab-btn[data-id=${tabIdx}]`).classList.add('active')
}

function ResetButtons(){
   buttons.forEach(btn=> {
     btn.classList.remove("active");
   });
}

// add eventlisteners to all the maintab 
mainTabs.forEach(function(tab){
  tab.addEventListener("click", function(e){
     var id = e.target.getAttribute("data-id");
     ResetButtons();
     SetContent(id);
     e.target.classList.add("active");
  });
});

// add eventlisteners to all the childtabs button
childTabs.forEach(function(tab){
  tab.addEventListener("click", function(e){
     var id = e.target.getAttribute("data-id");
     SetContent(id);
     ResetButtons();
     const button = document.querySelector(`.main-tab-btn[data-id="${id}"]`);
      button.classList.add("active");
      e.target.classList.add("active");
  })
})

//outer tab child button and outer content
childTabsBtn.forEach(tab => {
  tab.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const target = document
    .querySelector(tab.dataset.tabValue);
    childTabsContent.forEach(tabInfo => {
      tabInfo.classList.remove('active')
    })
    target.classList.add('active');
  })
})
```

If you want and explanation

I haved added a code to add active class

```
document.querySelector(`.child-tab-btn[data-id=${tabIdx}]`).classList.add('active')
```

and
sent this line back as it always reset the buttons so you have to add active after resetting the buttons

```
  ResetButtons();
  SetContent(id);
```

Comment: Got some problem with your code. If you click the 'Main tab 2' the content for 'Outer tab 3' is not working, the content supposed to be 'Outer tab 3 content' not 'Outer tab 1 content'.

Answer (score 1):

You're describing a tree structure in the text, but the markup isn't a tree. Instead, you're trying to emulate a tree using very dispersed HTML structure, which leads to complicated script and very error prone attributing of the HTML elements. Indexed `id`s and `class`es are not recommended, they're a nightmare to maintain, especially when having dynamic content.

That said, implement tabs using a real tree structure, you'll get a light-weigth reusable script with minimum effort, something like this:

```js
const tabSys = document.querySelector('.tabbed');

tabSys.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let index, branch, tab, actives,
    button = e.target.closest('button');
  if (!button) {return;} // Quit, not a button clicked

  // Get a branch and the correct tab to open
  index = button.getAttribute('data-index');
  branch = button.parentElement.querySelector('.tabs');
  tab = (branch.children)[index]; // index connects buttons to HTML structure

  // Hide active tabs in other branches
  actives = branch.querySelectorAll('.active');
  actives.forEach(active => {
    if (!active.contains(tab)) {
      active.classList.remove('active');
    }
  });

  // Show the selected tab
  tab.classList.add('active');

  // Open the first branch below the clicked button
  button = tab.querySelector('button');
  if (button) {
    button.click();
  }
});
```

```css
.tab {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabbed">
  <button data-index="0">Main tab 1</button>
  <button data-index="1">Main tab 2</button>
  <button data-index="2">Main tab 3</button>
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab active">
      <div>Main Tab 1 Content</div>
      <button data-index="0">Subtab 1.1</button>
      <button data-index="1">Subtab 1.2</button>
      <div class="tabs">
        <div class="tab active">Subtab 1.1 content</div>
        <div class="tab">Subtab 1.2 content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <div>Main Tab 2 Content</div>
      <button data-index="0">Subtab 2.1</button>
      <button data-index="1">Subtab 2.2</button>
      <div class="tabs">
        <div class="tab">Subtab 2.1 content</div>
        <div class="tab">Subtab 2.2 content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <div>Main Tab 3 Content</div>
      <button data-index="0">Subtab 3.1</button>
      <button data-index="1">Subtab 3.2</button>
      <button data-index="2">Subtab 3.3</button>
      <div class="tabs">
        <div class="tab">Subtab 3.1 content</div>
        <div class="tab">Subtab 3.2 content</div>
        <div class="tab">
          <div>Subtab 3.3 content</div>
          <button data-index="0">Subtab 3.3.1</button>
          <button data-index="1">Subtab 3.3.2</button>
          <div class="tabs">
            <div class="tab">Subtab 3.3.1 content</div>
            <div class="tab">Subtab 3.3.2 content</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice, that all the styling classes are stripped off, that makes the use of the classes more clear in the answer, you can add all the needed classes to the elements, ofcourse.

Comment: Yeah I know its a complex structure and JS but I'm just following what's in the UI functionality, and thats why I created that kind of structure. Maybe you can scrap my JS and structure but I need to follow UI functionality that showing the 'Main tab 1',  'Main tab 2' and its children tabs of "Outer tab 1" to "Outer tab 4".

Comment: @clarkf Doesn't my code do what you need? Or do you mean the markup is more or less given, and you can't change it?

Comment: Your code is very helpful and I will save it because I can use it at any given time, but for this question your code it not what I need. The UI insist that onload/refresh the 'Main tab 1' and 'Outer tab 1' will be the active tabs, and If i click the 'Main tab 2' the "Outer tab 3" became the active tab. Please check my code snippet and my comments above

Comment: @clarkf But that's what my code does. I've just renamed "Outer tabs" to "Subtabs" and added the third tab to demonstrate how flexible the code is.

Comment: Teemu I think so, please bear with me, check my codepen here https://codepen.io/graydirt/pen/PoXXYZa so far the only problem in that link is if you click the 'Main tab 2' the content for 'Outer tab 3' is not working, the content supposed to be 'Outer tab 3 content' not 'Outer tab 1 content', ite means that the 'Outer tab NUMBERS content' are not updating when clicking the 'Main tab 1' and 'Main tab 2'. Please note that the "Outer tab 1" and "Outer tab 2" are under "Main tab 1" and "Outer tab 3" and "Outer tab 4" are under "Main tab 2".